# How to post,get,put and delete the webAPIjson data in android?

Tags: android, web-services, rest, android-studio

How to post,get,put and delete the webAPI json data in android?

I have a rest api.Example:http:\www.yyyyy.com\zzzzzz something.
i want to post,get,put and delete data for this API.could you anyone explain the concepts clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this 2 libs:

- http://square.github.io/retrofit/
- https://github.com/google/gson

They are easy to use, and Retrofit have a converter for GSON. If you need help, i'm here.